# Insert IF function to a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to use vba to place an IF function into a cell which is 8 columns to the right of the active cell. The IF function compares the value of the cell 2 columns to the left of the active cell.

So far i have tried various variations of the below but can't seem to get it to work, any ideas?

```
targetRange.Ofsett(0, 8).Formula = "=IF(" & targetRange.Ofsett(0, -2).Address & " =""FAIL"",""Enter Required Data"","""")"
targetRange.Ofsett(0, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[0]C[-10]=""FAIL"",""Enter Required Data"","""")"
```

Comment: I would have thought that the most cursory research would have alerted you to a problem with `Ofsett` .

Comment: You are correct

Comment: Problem sorted then?

Comment: Not quite, Now both cells have `#VALUE!` and I haven't had time to look into it yet. If it helps with debugging the reason. The process is started when the person clicks a hyperlink inside a cell.